# Change my password or where is the My Login page loctaed

Tags: support, user-accounts, password

In the changing password I'm suggested to navigate to the My Login page. After logging on I`m unable to locate this page or Edit Settings.

Answer (score 2):

Try

https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/current

or maybe

https://stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/current

if that somehow doesn't work.

The 'My logins' item is located on the left of the 'Edit profile and settings' tab:

[image]

On the right, there's a link to change your password. That will take you to this page:

[image]